# How to edit text position in Unity with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move text in my game with C# but I am not sure how to get a hold of the actual text nor do I know how to move it's position.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You need to formulate better your question your description is very plane and too ambiguous. What kind of "text" (what component are you using? there is a lot of ways to print a 3D text on unity) are you trying to manipulate? How? Why? What kind of transformation do you need?

Comment: @Frohlich I am new to unity so some of these things are difficult for me to answer. I am doing a 2D game for starters and I just want to move my text along the x axis. I am not sure what type of text it is, I can find out with some help.

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to move your position of the text by using script? Is your text using the UI system of Unity or it is an image/sprite?

You could do something like:
For UI text:

```
Text yourText = Gameobject.Find("the name of your text gameobject").GetComponent<Text>();

yourText.transform.position = new Vector3(posX,posY,posZ);//where posX Y Z is the position where you want to put your text.
```

If the text you mentioned is a sprite/image, you can use the similar way:

```
Gameobject yourText = Gameobject.Find("the name of your text gameobject").GetComponent<GameObject>();

yourText.transform.position = new Vector3(posX,posY,posZ);//where posX Y Z is the position where you want to put your text.
```

Hope this is helpful...

Comment: Think if you GetComponent<Text>() from your gameObject you will not have an transfor at yourText, am I right? Also you dont need to GetComponent<GameObject>() from GameObject.Find() because it return a GameObject.

Comment: @Ares I'm not sure whether it is UI or a Sprite. However, both methods of code throw an error. The UI method says: `The type or namespace name 'Text' could not be found.` The Sprite method says: `The type or namespace name 'Gameobject' could not be found.`

Comment: The namespaces problem is because you need to import them declaring "using UnityEngine.UI.Text" or "using UnityEngine.UI.Sprite". I'll try to answer providing some information that I think will help you to leran about what you are trying to use.

Comment: I get `The type or namespace name 'Sprite' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.UI'.` I apologize for the late response, I've been busy, I should be able to follow up quicker now.

Comment: @Frohlich, trying to research this. Not much luck.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Sprites class is under UnityEngine namespace... You can find it very easy by looking at the API references that I linked on my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you told that you are trying to make a 2D game I'll assume you are using Unity 5 and trying to use new UI system so you can learn it's mechanics [here](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui) on video lessons and [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html) on the manual about it. The API references are [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) to evolve after learn the NUI system's basics.

If you are trying to use GUIText component please let us know because it's a bit different.

If my assumption is wrong and you are not using unity 4.6+ with new UI system you may have something like OnGUI(){blah} on your script and there you are trying to move your text. So let us know this king of details because it is huge different from another ones that I mentioned above.